# How to specify nano version installed by homebrew in nanorc?

Tags: editor, settings, nano

When I set the syntax color setting in nanorc, I wrote like below.

```
include "/usr/local/Cellar/nano/[nano_version]/share/nano/*"
```

But I upgrade the nano version and deleted the old version. (brew upgrade with cleanup option)

The setting was corrupted and I needed to modify to the certain version.
To avoid the modification, I wrote the setting below.

```
include "/usr/local/Cellar/nano/*/share/nano/*"
```

It is worked if there is one version directory.

What is a best practice to set the correct version even for multiple versions in the directory?

Answer (score 1):

Nano does not seem to have much support for complicated logic in [configuration files](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html). The version handling will need to be done by something smarter: one option is writing a script that updates the config file to the highest version found.
(To be fair, if you have to run a script each time you update, it doesn't lessen the workload very much from just deleting the old nano. That would be the alternative.)